# C# variable value being assigned incorrectly issue

Tags: c#, variables, global-variables

I have written a method with the idea of keeping a certain variable in memory in order to optimize the program. The issue i'm having is that in the variable `previousSearchInfoForSavings`seems to always be the same as `searchInfo` even though it shouldn't be as it is only assigned in certain places.

The idea is that if you pass in the same `searchInfo` array it will recognise that it is the same as `previousSearchInfoForSavings` and not run the `ClearPageNavigation.main` method.

However this does not seem to be the case. If different values are passed in for `searchInfo` it doesn't seem to matter and and `previousSearchInfoForSavings`seems to automatically update to these values.

For example:

If I pass in {"X","Y","Z"} in as `searchInfo` the first time `previousSearchInfoForSavings` is null so it will enter that if statement. This is fine. The next time if I pass in {"A","B","C"} at the beginning (where the comments are) these arrays are already equal. This should not be the case.

My code:

```
private static TableRow[] TRforSavings = null;
private static string[] previousSearchInfoForSavings = null;

public static bool[] main(
    string[] searchInfo,
    string[] compareInfo,
    string ClearFinancesTestPageURL
) {             
    if (searchInfo[1] == "Savings") {
        //searchInfo == previousSearchInfoForSavings here 
         bool[] results;
         if (previousSearchInfoForSavings == null) {
             previousSearchInfoForSavings = searchInfo;
             TableRow[] TR = ClearPageNavigation.main(
                  ClearFinancesTestPageURL,
                  searchInfo[0],
                  searchInfo[1],
                  searchInfo[2],
                  searchInfo[3]
             );
             results = CompareSavings.main(TR, compareInfo);
             TRforSavings = TR;
         } else {
             if (ArraysEqual(previousSearchInfoForSavings, searchInfo)) {
                 results = CompareSavings.main(TRforSavings, compareInfo);
             } else {
                 TableRow[] TR = ClearPageNavigation.main(
                     ClearFinancesTestPageURL,
                     searchInfo[0],
                     searchInfo[1],
                     searchInfo[2],
                     searchInfo[3]
                 );
                 results = CompareSavings.main(TR, compareInfo);
                 TRforSavings = TR;
                 previousSearchInfoForSavings = searchInfo;
            }
        }
        //searchInfo == previousSearchInfoForSavings here
        return results;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you pass {"X","Y","Z"} or {"A","B","C"} in as `searchInfo` (as claimed), surely the very first `if` test means it does: nothing...?

Comment: Can we see this with a repro? i.e. a `static void Main() { ... HERE ...}` that calls this method and has the effect you are seeing?

Comment: Can you include the implementation of the `ArraysEqual` method?

Comment: @MarcGravell the first does mean nothing in this case but it is cut from larger code, three of the same sections of code but for different values of `searchInfo[1]`I have only been trying `searchInfo[1]==savings` so the others have nothing to do with the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using reference types, and you should be cloning "searchInfo" instead of setting "previousSearchInfoForSavings" to be equal to it. So instead of:

```
previousSearchInfoForSavings = searchInfo;
```

You should be doing something like:

```
previousSearchInfoForSavings = (string[])searchInfo.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens because you are assigning previousSearchInfoForSavings = searchInfo and thus copying searchInfo's reference in your local variable. And I suspect that you are sending the same searchInfo into your main method with changed values and that's why array elements change in both instances. To avoid this you have to copy searchInfo elements into previousSearchInfoForSavings instead of assigning.